# Store session in MemCache instead of default session storage in Yii 1.x

Tags: session, yii, memcached

This is the code, that I've added to `config/main.php` in my Yii 1.x application:

```
   'mCache' => array(
        'class' => 'system.caching.CMemCache',
        'useMemcached'=>true,
        'keyPrefix'=>'',
        'hashKey'=>false,
        'serializer'=>false,
        'servers' => array(
            array('host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 10000)
        ),
    ),

    'session' => array(
        'sessionName' => 'PHPSESSID',
        'class' => 'CCacheHttpSession',
        'autoStart' => true,
        'cacheID' => 'mCache',
        'cookieMode' => 'only',
        'timeout' => 1200
    ),
```

What should I do next, to force Yii to use `CMemCache`, instead of default session storage?

Comment: Since you're new to Stack Overflow, please, show some effort before asking questions here. Google around, read documentation, etc. Don't just ask questions, that can be answered within five minutes or by reading first paragraphs of official documentation. If you fail to do something yourself, your questions will be downvoted, closed or not answered at all.

Comment: trejder i know i am new to stack overflow . that does not mean that i didn't took effort to search on google or other resources.i have some confusion regarding to the storing in memcache.so that's why i asked you.My intention is no to get answer within five minutes.If it is stupid question but new to me.So i expected good answer.by the way thanks  for your answer and efforts towards my question.i ll take care before next stupidity .thanks

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I wasn't mean to tell, that your question is stupid. No, way. I just wanted to point you, that you should _show_ your effort. You didn't wrote anything in the question itself about, what you have done to solve the problem. That's all. Don't take this personally. I just wanted to avoid, that someone will close your question. BTW: If you want to express your "thanks" here, simply upvote answer, comment or question! :]

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is old, but this configuration works

```
    'memcacheConn'=>array(
        'class'=>'CMemCache',
        'servers'=>array(
            array(
                'host'=>'172.17.0.1',
                'port'=>11211,
                //'weight'=>60,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'class' => 'CCacheHttpSession',
        'autoStart' => true,
        'cacheID' => 'memcacheConn',
        'cookieMode' => 'allow',
        'sessionName' => 'MYSSIONNAME',

    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you read introduction to [`CMemCache`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMemCache/) in Yii 1.x API documentation? I think you didn't. In first paragraphs of this document, you have an example, how to use `CMemCache` in Yii 1.x.

Change `'class'=>'CCacheHttpSession'` into `'class'=>'CMemCache'` in your `session` key of configuration file. And you don't have to register `CMemCache` as separate component, like you did in your example (`mCache`). You can configure it directly in `session` configuration key.

An example from [Yii 1.x API documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMemCache/):

```
array
(
    'components'=>array
    (
        'cache'=>array
        (
            'class'=>'CMemCache',
            'servers'=>array
            (
                array
                (
                    'host'=>'server1',
                    'port'=>11211,
                    'weight'=>60,
                ),
                array
                (
                    'host'=>'server2',
                    'port'=>11211,
                    'weight'=>40,
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: just replacing Change 'class'=>'CCacheHttpSession' into 'class'=>'CMemCache' in `your session does not work. Yii expects a Session Object, not a Cache Object.